# How to find window handles for all instances of the same application (for example calc.exe)

Tags: delphi

Let's say I have 4 instances of calc.exe running and I must close them all programmatically from my app. Is there any way to collect all handles (to an array) for all instances at once instead of using code below in this ugly loop?

```
procedure CloseAppGracefully(WindowTitle: string);
var 
  WindowHandle,
  LastWindowHandle: hwnd;
begin
  LastWindowHandle := 0;

  repeat
    WindowHandle := FindWindow(nil, PChar(WindowTitle));

    if (WindowHandle <> 0) and (LastWindowHandle <> WindowHandle) then
    begin
      LastWindowHandle := WindowHandle;
      SendMessage(WindowHandle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_CLOSE, 0);
    end;
  until WindowHandle = 0;
end;
```

Comment: EnumWindows and GetWindowThreadProcessId

Comment: madCollection provides this with function Processes: http://help.madshi.net/Processes.htm

Comment: you can find some source in this very old post http://www.delphigroups.info/2/19/488912.html